# How to get orginal attributes of datatable?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I fetch datatable in entity framework, however when I use, `Dbcontext.Classname` it gives me all attributes which are coming from joined table to this table.
However, I want to get just original attributes of this table. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to load only fields from the current entity?

You need to disable [lazy-loading](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/lazyloading-in-entity-framework.aspx) in your `DbContext`. This can be down by setting `LazyLoadingEnabled` to false in your `DbContext` constructor:

```
public partial class SampleContext : DbContext
{
    public SampleContext (): base(...)
    {
        // disable lazy-loading in your db-context
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Then, whenever you run a query, it only queries the fields related to the selected `DbSet`. For example, imagine we have a `City` and `Country` entities.

**City Table**

```
CityId | Name   | CountryId 
-------------------------
1      | Tehran | 98
```

**Country Table**

```
CountryId | Name   | Culture
-------------------------
98        | Iran   | fa-IR
```

And their entity models are like:

```
public class Country
{
  public int CountryId{get;set;}
  pulic string Name{get;set;}
  public string Culture{get;set;}
}

public class City
{
   public int CityId{get;set;}
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public Country Country{get;set;}
}
```

We are going to select a city with id 1:

```
using(var dbContext = new SampleDbContext())
{
  var city = dbContext.Cities.SingleOrDefault(c => c.CityId == 1);

  var country = city.Country;
  // country will be null
  // because EF didn't fetch its data, because it's an eager-load
}
```

The query above generate query like:

```
   SELECT * FROM Cities WHERE CityId = 1
```

And as I mentioned in the code comments above, `City.Country` will be null due to using `eager-loading`. In this case to load navigation properties you can use `Include` method.

```
using(var dbContext = new SampleDbContext())
{
  var city = dbContext.Cities
                      .Include(c => c.Country)
                      .SingleOrDefault(c => c.CityId == 1);
}
```

The query will generate SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Cities ci
INNER JOIN Countries c ON ci.CountryId = c.CountryId
```

Addition to the eager-loading, don't forget that you can always use projection in your queries. For example, in our sample we need to fetch only CityName and CountryName:

```
using(var dbContext = new SampleDbContext())
{
  var cities=dbContext.Cities
                      .Include(c => c.Country)
                      .Select(new {CityName=c.Name, CountryName=c.Country.Name}
                      .ToList();
}
```

This only selects two columns:

```
SELECT 
   ci.Name as CityName,
   c.Name as CountryName
FROM
  Cities ci
INNER JOIN Countries c 
      ON ci.CountryId = c.CountryId
```

I hope I could describe it well to you.